# How can I attach event handlers to items generated using databinding in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, pixelsense

I am developing for a MS Surface unit and am using a `ScatterView` to display some data. The scenario below probably fits a normal `ListBox` (and `ListBoxItems`) too.

When I databind the `ScatterView`, WPF automatically wraps the contents of the `DataTemplate` with `ScatterViewItems`. I want to attach some event handers for the `ScatterManipulationCompleted` event of the (generated) `ScatterViewItem`, but can't figure out how to do that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `Style` on the container type and specify an `EventSetter` like this:

```
<surface:ScatterView>
    <surface:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type surface:ScatterViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="ScatterManipulationCompleted" Handler="myHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </surface:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
</surface:ScatterView>
```

Comment: Yep, way better than my solution :-|

Comment: Why go through the trouble? Plus using EventSetters can severly limit your flexibility in storing your ItemContainerStyle as it must be stored as a resource in XAML that has code behind. Why not just use the routed events approach outlined by Ben?

Comment: This approach allows you to keep event logic with the Style. Nothing stops you from having code-behind with your resource dictionaries. Besides that, it keeps the event declaration closer to the thing it belongs to, making the XAML easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of routed events. You can just listen for this event at the ScatterView level.

```
        <surface:ScatterView surface:ScatterViewItem.ScatterManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As so often happens, I now found the/a answer. I've been looking at this for the last 20 hours or so, only to find it 5 minutes after posting the question :-(

Any way: the solution I found and which helps me for now is to use the Loaded event of the ScatterView. In the handler, I have the following loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MiniBrowserContent.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ScatterViewItem svItem = (ScatterViewItem)(MiniBrowserContent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
    svItem.ScatterManipulationCompleted += new ScatterManipulationCompletedEventHandler(svItem_ScatterManipulationCompleted);
}
```

It all came to me after reading http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=7

Hope this helps anybody else.

Bye,
Bart

Comment: This only works if you never add an additional SVI to your SV. You should use the routed events approach outlined by Ben.